# Winsock2's listen() function finds a connection for every port; even those that don't exist?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, winsock2

I'm attempting to create a method that listens for a connection request to a specific port using a TCP protocol, with no libraries other than those that come with the Windows OS. The method seems to work fine with creating a socket and binding to a port; the problem seems to be with the listen() function. Even with no connection request to any port, it continually returns the value of zero, meaning, straight off of Microsoft's website -

> If no error occurs, listen returns zero.

The strange part is that this happens with all port values; it seems to find a connection request for randomly attempted ports, ranging from 1234, to 8000, to -154326. For each of these, it's returning a value of zero.

What it should be doing is continually running until a connection request is found (this is what SOMAXCONN apparently indicates); once again, straight off of Microsoft's website -

> If there are no available socket descriptors, listen attempts to continue to function.

Here is the method itself -

```
bool listenOnPort(SOCKET networkSocket, int portNumber) {
    WSADATA wsadata;
    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);
    if(error) {
        cout << "Failed to start up Windows Sockets API." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202) {
        WSACleanup();
        cout << "Failed to find a valid Windows Sockets API." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    networkSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(networkSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Failed to create a network socket." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    if(bind(networkSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)&address, sizeof(address)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "Failed to bind to the port." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    cout << "Listening for a connection to port " << portNumber <<"..." << endl;
    listen(networkSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    cout << "Found a connection!" << endl;
}
```

Any explanation/word of advice is appreciated - thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen

listen() marks the socket referred to by sockfd as a passive socket, that is, as a socket that will be used to accept incoming connection requests using accept(2).

You must call "listen()" before you can call "accept()"; but "accept()" is the call that accepts new connections (and gives you a new socket for each new connection).

Here's the man page for "accept()":

http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept

Better, look at Beej's Guide for an excellent introduction to sockets programming:

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/

PS:

And don't forget to call WSAStartup() if you're using Windows sockets :)

Comment: +1 for taking the time to provide documentation links (although "Here's the man page for accept()" actually links to connect())

Answer (score 3):

You've confused `listen` with `accept`.  `listen` reserves the port for your application, and queues incoming connections.  `accept` waits for an incoming connection (if one isn't already queued).

`listen` will succeed when there is no incoming connection attempt.

Comment: From what I know, listen() should be waiting for a connection request, and then giving the option of accepting, which creates the connection. Is this wrong?

Comment: @Simon: That is wrong.  `listen` tells the OS to expect connection requests.  It does not wait for a connection.  `accept` is the function that waits for a connection.

Comment: Ah, well if this is true, then it looks like the guide I am using to learn is incorrect. bit.ly/FQcVbl claims that this is true (if you're interested in explaining how I possibly could have interpreted this wrong, it's the paragraph right before the section on "Asynchronous Sockets").

Comment: No, you're reading the guide incorrectly.  Instead of a (blocking) "accept()", the guide uses (an asynchronous) "WSAAsyncSelect()", which expects to be able to handle any number of events.  Read Beej's guide (cited above) for a good explanation of "sockets".  Things like WSAAsyncSelect() are Microsoft extensions.  And if you're going to use Microsoft-specific APIs, please do consider alternatives like C#/.Net.

Comment: @paulsm4: No, it's the guide that is at fault here.

Comment: @Simon bit.ly/FQcVbl is 100% wrong on this point despite repeating it several times. It is also wrong about what the second parameter to `listen()` is for, and makes the thoroughly stupid recommendation of passing SOMAXCONN, which is 0x7fffffff, a ridiculous size for a backlog queue. Not that he knows what it's for.